# Catch the download link automatically like IDM?

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Here is my code for downloading a file I am passing a URL, but I want to make my download manager catch the link automatically

```
   private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    string []filename;
        string fn ; fn=textBox1.Text;
        int i;
    filename =fn.Split('/');
    for (i = 1; i <= filename.Length; i++) ;
        string oname=filename[i-2];

    //////// Starts the download

    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://dinirah.wen.ru/Internet-k-zariye-musalmano-gumrah-kia-ja-raha.mp3"), textBox2.Text+"\\"+oname);

      //////// the above i passed the url to download.

        label4.Text = i.ToString();
    button1.Text = "Download In Process";
    button1.Enabled = false;

    }
```

Now I want to make my downloader automatically get the download url, and store it in a string which it then passes as an URL later.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a WebBrowser control, or with a standalone web browser?

Comment: web browser like chrome firefox etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should develop browser extension(s) and then you would be able to intercept the file download process.

The other way is to monitor your computer's network connections and intercept when a desired file type is being requested. I have found that IDM intercepts my downloads even if I am downloading it using my programs (If enabled in IDM to intercept any download). Be careful with windows update files, diagnostic files and any other unknown file.